# Contract with a struct argument can't receive ETH?

Tags: solidity, payable

I have this minimal contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

struct Order {
    address trader;
    uint256 amount;
}

contract Test {
    event Received(address, uint256);

    function openPosition(Order calldata order) external payable {
        emit Received(order.trader, msg.value);
    }
}
```

where `openPosition` has `payable` and should be able to receive ETH.

But after deployment, tried on etherscan, no matter what `payableAmount` I'm inputting (and I made sure the wallet has enough Goerli ETH), the contract always receives 0 ETH (the msg.value is always 0). I'm attaching a screenshot of etherscan.[image]

If I replace the `Order calldata order` with `address trader`. The contract can receive ETH.

Why is the struct argument interfering with the `msg.value` here?

Really appreciated any help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the contract address? Are you using the latest metamask version? Sometimes testnet sites aren't well maintained. Can you try calling the contract from a more advanced interface, like remix, or MyEtherWallet?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related to the struct argument, but rather to the way you are calling the contract function on Etherscan. When you call a function that expects a struct as argument, you must pass the values in a specific format to properly interact with contract.

When you are using Etherscan, make sure you are providing the correct ABI-encoded data for the function call. In this case, ABI-encoded data for the openPosition function should include the Order struct data and the value you want to send as ETH.

Here's an example of how to encode the data for the openPosition function using the web3.js library:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://goerli.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_API_KEY');

const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"tuple","name":"order","type":"tuple"}],"name":"openPosition","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"Received","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"event"}];
const contractAddress = 'your contract';
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

const trader = 'address';
const amount = web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether'); // 0.1 ether

const data = contract.methods.openPosition({trader: trader, amount: amount}).encodeABI();
console.log(data);
```

now use this to call openPosition.
You just need to properly encode the data when calling the function on Etherscan.

please, upvote and accept the answer if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was using `forge verify-contract` for the contract on etherscan, after which they automatically pick up the input format for the order struct and payableAmount. So question: is this not the proper way of making the contract interactable through etherscan?

Comment: I can see the difference is that I have `"internalType":"struct Order","name":"order","type":"tuple"}`, whereas your `internalType` is `tuple`. Wondering how I can make sure this is correct in etherscan when verifying the contract using `forge verify-contract`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me

[image]

Comment: what is your contract verification steps? I'm using `forge verify-contract` and suspect it has some problem.

Comment: you are testing on BSC instead of Ethereum